# How to data display data in innerHTML when dynamically button click using javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is my code, when i click edit button, the "msg" div opens and retrieves the corresponding message. But it displays message only in first div "msg" and when i click second or third edit button its shows only first row div. "msg" does not display the second or third div "msg".

```
{% for datas in data %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">        
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                            <a href="{% url 'profile' datas.id %}">{{datas.user_id|capfirst}}</a></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class=" col-md-6 text-right" > 
                        {% if request.user.id == datas.user_id_id %}
                            <button id="edit" value="{{datas.post}}" onclick="edit(this)">Edit</button> 
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="msg">
                <hr>
                {{datas.post}}
                <hr>
                </div>              
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></div> 
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">{{datas.post_date}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<script type="text/javascript">
function edit(id)
{
    var body = id.value;
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML  = '<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}<div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" name="edit_post" rows="3">'+body+'</textarea><br> <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">POST</button></div><div></form>';
}
</script>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you use same id ( as you have used for edit button and msg div) for multiple elements, you would get such problems. you should use class instead.

Comment: ... or unique id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML id are should be unique, better use classes. If you have multiple element with the same id *document.getElementById("msg")* will only return the first match.

But you can solve this problem by going to the parent element ".card-body" of the clicked element (which is button, I see you passed "this") then use querySelector to find the "msg" id inside card-body.

```
function edit(elem)
{
  var parentcard = elem.closest(".card-body")
  parentcard.querySelector("#msg").innerHTML  = "content here"
}
```

where elem is the passed 'this' parameter

Comment: Dear Nikko Laurenciana, Thanks for your valuable reply and also it's working. And I have one more doubt regarding,  edit and post the corresponding message. How do I fetch corresponding data id and post in database in python django.

Comment: Hi Kumar, you're welcome. Please mark my answer as the answer if it solved your problem.

Regarding the data id,  you can add it as parameter in the **edit** function example in button onlick set _edit(this, {% datas.id %})_. Then inside the edit function as a second parameter you can do whatever you want with the datas.id.